# Select data from complicated xml in sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have this XML:

```
<Articles> 
    <Article> 
        <ArticleNo>31213496</Article_No> 
        <ArticleDes>PRESSNING</ArticleDes> 
        <Notes></Notes> 
        <EstimatedCycleTime>2.05714285714286</EstimatedCycleTime> 
        <Departments> 
            <Department isLinked="true" name="Finnveden Olofström" /> 
            <Department isLinked="false" name="3333333333" /> 
            <Department isLinked="true" name="company_hide" /> 
          <Department isLinked="false" name="Department1" /> 
      </Departments> 
    </Article> 
</Articles>
```

I use this SQL to select Articles data:

```
declare  
        @articleNo nvarchar(25), 
        @articleDes nvarchar(255), 
        @notes nvarchar(max), 
        @cycleTime float  
declare cls cursor scroll for 
        select a.value('Article_No[1]','nvarchar(25)'), a.value('ArticleDes[1]','nvarchar(255)'),a.value('Notes[1]','nvarchar(max)'),a.value('EstimatedCycleTime[1]','float') 
        from @xml.nodes('Articles/Article') as a(a) 
open cls 
fetch next from cls into @articleNo, @articleDes, @notes, @cycleTime 
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
begin 
        select @articleNo, @articleDes, @notes, @cycleTime 
        fetch next from cls into @articleNo, @articleDes, @notes, @cycleTime 
end 
close cls 
deallocate cls
```

How do I select departments names which have `isLinked="true"` for each `Article`?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!
That way, you can avoid all those messy `&nbsp;`, `<br/>` etc. tags, too!!

Comment: PS: your opening tag `<ArticleNo>` doesn't match the closing tag `</Article_No>` - probably just a typo, but be sure those tags match!

Comment: Yes, it is a typo, xml automatically generated so there will be no issues with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely **no need** for a messy cursor here! Just use the native XQuery support in SQL Server:

```
SELECT
    a.value('Article_No[1]','nvarchar(25)'), 
    a.value('ArticleDes[1]','nvarchar(255)'),
    a.value('Notes[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
    a.value('EstimatedCycleTime[1]', 'decimal(28,14)') ,
    DepartmentName = d.value('@name', 'nvarchar(50)')
FROM
    @xml.nodes('Articles/Article') as a(a) 
CROSS APPLY
    a.nodes('Departments/Department') AS d(d)
WHERE
    d.value('@isLinked', 'varchar(10)') = 'true'
```

This will give an output of:

[image]

Since you have *multiple* departments for each `<Article>` node, you need to use the `CROSS APPLY` operator and define yet another `.nodes()` list of XML subelements to get at all the departments defined.

Comment: I'm using cursor because I need to check if article exists in DB and if so then update it and insert new in other case. Also I need to insert list of articles (previously get IDs of that articles) to ArticleDepartments table. Of cause it can be done without cursor - just insert result of select into temp table, update that table with department id and update data using "update select from" and "insert select from" statements, but what the difference? As for me cursor easier to read.

Comment: @Mardok: cursors are **notoriously** slow and go against all the basics of **set-based** programming in SQL Server. **AVOID** cursor whenever you can! Using a temporary table will most likely be **much faster** than a messy cursor!